# Поиск вырожденных последовательностей в структурах ДНК с использованием регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, биоинформатика

Есть задачи для сервера - искать определенные последовательности в структуре ДНК. Они ставятся по-разному: иногда нужно найти ближайшую последовательность, иногда - все возможные, но чаще всего - найти первую и последнюю.

Если упростить, то есть длинная строка (не менее 8 тысяч символов, алфавит - A, G, T, C) и короткие (не более 12 символов) строки, которые нужно искать. Если строка не вырождена (пример: AACGTT), то задача проста - `strpos()` и `strrpos()` дают нормальный по скорости результат, а, главное, - сам результат.

Но если строка вырождена, например, AAWWTT, где W - это C или G, или ещё хуже - CCN(7)GG, где N(7) - это 7 любых символов A, G, T или С, то, как я понимаю, проще всего идти через, например, `preg_match_all()`.

```
$dna = "AGTC......GTC"; //ДНК-последовательность, длинная строка, берётся из базы, в ней практически гарантированно есть наши искомые строки
$pattern1 = "AA(C|G){2}TT"; // AAWWTT
$pattern2 = "CC.{7}GG"; // CCN(7)GG
$matches = array(); // тут будут результаты
```

теперь, если просто запустить

```
if (preg_match_all($pattern1,$ldna,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) === false) 
// PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE используем, чтобы получить позиции 

{
// не нашли - обрабатываем ситуацию, она редка
}
else {
    $k1 = $matches[count($matches)-1][1];
}
```

то имеем две ошибки: "**Undefined offset**" - это, видимо, из-за того, что массив $matches у нас пуст, поэтому count() к нему неприменимо

и "**preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash**" - а вот с этой ошибкой я не могу разобраться. Я неправильно использую `preg_match_all()`? Или я так и не научился строить регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

паттерн заключается в разделители. обычно это `/`. То есть `/AA(C|G){2}TT/`.

Если вам группы захвата сами не нужны, и достаточно будет поиска позиции вхождения, то группы захвата мб не стоит писать. либо использовать non-capturing.

```
$pattern1 = "/AA([CG]{2})TT/";   // AAWWTT
$pattern2 = "/CC([AGTC]{7})GG/"; // CCN(7)GG
```

точка используется как любой символ. поскольку ваш алфавит ограничен (пусть и других в строке не встретится), возможно,будет более эффективно использовать не `.{7}` а `[AGTC]{7}`, но этот вопрос лучше проверить на практике.

что касается первой ошибки, то сделайте `print_r($matches)` чтобы уточнить по правильным ли индексам обращаетесь.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо! Группы захвата, возможно, понадобятся. Осталось понять, как сориентироваться в массиве:  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => CCCGAAACTGG [1] => 150 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => CCTGCATCCGG [1] => 214 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => CCGTCTCGTGG [1] => 455 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => CCGTGTTGTGG [1] => 542 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => CCCCATCATGG [1] => 573 ) ) )     $matches теперь трёхмерный?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov так на последнем уровне сами совпадения и смещение. самый первый уровень - на нулевой позиции - полное соответствие, индекс 1 - первая группа, и так далее. средний уровень - это перечисление соответсвий, т.к. `match_all`. В итоге - группа захвата -> номер соответствия -> само соответствие. Если групп захвата в выражении нет, то на верхнем уровне в массиве будет только один элемент, иначе по числу групп + 1.